# Is it possible to query Nest API rate limits?

Tags: android, nest-api

I've just noticed that it's very easy to hit request rate limit.
Is it possible to get info about current rate limit ?
Also, when we receive rate limit error, is there any event / listener to be notified when we can send requests again ?
How can I increase rate limit ?

Documentation at https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/data-rate-limits/ does not provide any specific numbers unfortunately.

P.S. I'm using Android SDK https://github.com/nestlabs/android-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to query or increase the rate limit. The rate limit is dynamic and designed to preserve the battery life of the consumer's thermostat. To preserve battery life, they are applied to all developers writing data to the thermostat.

So if developer-A makes `x` requests in an hour, and developer-B makes `y`, the total requests are `x+y`, and an evaluation is made in real time whether the thermostat's battery can handle that many updates. If not, all developers are rate limited until the thermostat's battery has recharged enough for more updates.

Comment: Sad. There'll be good to have some data in response, which will return at least approximate number of api requests left for next time range (minutes/hour).